# How to style each component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I have following React code and it's CSS for a Scrolling functionality. When I am doing props.children.map it is giving me an error "TypeError: props.children.map is not a function". It may be a simple mistake since I am still learning React.js. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

```
**Scroll.js**

import React from 'react';
import './Scroll.css'

const Scroll = (props) => {

    return(
        <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">

        {props.children.map((component) => 
        <div class="slide"> component </div>)
        }

        </div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Scroll;
```

**Scroll.css**

```
.slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.slide {
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you add how you are _using_ the `Scroll` component in your question please.

Comment: what is the children data?

Comment: This is how I am using Scroll component
<Scroll>                
 <CardList versions = {filteredVersions}/>
  </Scroll>

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting makes sense because `children` is just one `ReactNode` and `map` will only work on an array of multiple values.

You could do something like:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Scroll.css";

const Scroll = props => {
  return (
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Scroll;
```

And invoke `Scroll` like:

```
const SomeParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Scroll>
      <div>
        <SomeChild />
        <SomeChild />
        <SomeChild />
      </div>
    </Scroll>
  );
};
```

Comment: But I want to style each element in props.children array. The way you showed, styles the whole array and not each element separately.

Comment: Here map should ideally work because it has multiple values.

Comment: Well react will only accept 1 child node (your `CardList` component) so in your case it sounds like the styling should be done at a lower scope - inside the `CardList` component per card that you're rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can trasforme you css in object like

```
const styles = ({
input: {
    display: 'none',
},
pointerBorder: {
    borderWidth: '4px',
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    borderColor: 'grey',
    paddingTop: '40px',
    paddingBottom: '40px',
},
iconUpload: {
    fontSize: '100px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
}
```

});

it is just one example.
For to use, just call de object

```
            <div className={styles.input}>
```

One more thing.
try to comment the code

```
{props.children.map((component) => 
    <div class="slide"> component </div>)
    }
```

and run again, i think it is not a style probleam.

Comment: The title to the question is misleading, but if you read the full thing, Akshata Dabade is not asking about styles directly.

Comment: if you read again, you can see that i talk about style and the typeError

Comment: I see that you added that :)